# Uploading pdf files stored in iphone to server in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, file-upload

I am making an iphone application which is pretty much like forum. People can ask question and upload a **pdf/doc** file along with the question. Is there a way to access the **pdf/doc** file in iphone when user clicks upload button and send the file to server?

I have implemented the feature for image for which I used **UIImagePicker** to pick the image and send it to the server with http request. But I am completely lost and have no idea how to handle pdf/doc files in same manner.

Any help/suggestion really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to upload PDF and Doc files, then you can integrate **Dropbox** and **Google Drive** in your app and then select the files ,as Apple does not have centralised storage. If you notice **Apple also chooses the documents from Google Drive while composing a mail**.
So implementing and integrating google drive and Dropbox would be a good option.

Here is the link for Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios

Here is the link for Google Drive https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart

Implementing Google drive is a bit hard but dropbox is quite simple.

Wish it saves your time. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a combination of two things (both have been discussed here before and I include the links below).

(1) store a PDF. There are many options but the best way is to allow coredata to save outside the persistent store. Then store the reference to the file in core date. See: [Insert a PDF file into Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788414/insert-a-pdf-file-into-core-data)

(2) send the file to the server. There are many options for this as well. The fastest is probably to use a wrapper library such as [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). See: [File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)